# python related word search and replace with list words

Tags: python, parsing, data-conversion, error-correction

Consider this, I have a list; `list1=['car', 'bike', 'van', 'class']`, and I am parsing a text file. This text file can contain other arbitrary words that are not in this list and are not misspellings of words in this list.

- If 'ca' is in the file, my algorithm would replace it with 'car'
- If the file contains 'bke' it is replaced with 'bike'
- If the file contains 'clss', it is replaced with 'class'

My algorithm is basically an error correction algorithm. How do I replace the relevant misspelled words with the words in the list?

Any answer to the question will be appreciated!

Comment: How would we know which misspelled words qualify? One character off?

Comment: Are you trying to find simple typographical errors in the text file and replace those words with the closest in your list? What metric are you wanting to use to correct these mistakes? Are the only words in the text file the words found in your list of words? Or are there other words found in the input file as well? If other words can be found in the file what metric are you wanting to use to find if a word is a match for the list or not?

Comment: yes other words also,is there a tool to find every single word in file with some word in list which is atleast with 1/2 character off?

Comment: What exactly is '1/2 character off' mean?

Comment: it means eg:python also as pytho

Comment: I would edit the question to make your intention clear, but otherwise a good problem.

Comment: @adarshram read about Levenshtein distance and you can use: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-Levenshtein/0.11.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a levenshtein algorithm, you can do this:

```
tgt_list='ca bke clss'.split()    
for word in ['car','bike','van','class']:
    wdist_exp=((w, levenshtein(w, word)) for w in tgt_list)
    closest, dist=min(wdist_exp, key=lambda t: t[1])
    print '{}=>{}   ld={}'.format(closest,word,dist)
```

Prints:

```
ca=>car   ld=1
bke=>bike   ld=1
ca=>van   ld=2
clss=>class   ld=1
```

It is also possible with the [regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex):

```
import regex    

template='{}=>{} with {} substitutions, {} insertions, {} deletions'
tgt='ca bke clss'
for word in ['car','bike','van','class']:
    pat=r'((?:\b{}\b){{e<=2}})'.format(word)
    m=regex.search(pat, tgt, regex.BESTMATCH)     
    if m:
        print template.format(m.group(1),word,*m.fuzzy_counts)
```

Prints:

```
ca =>car with 1 substitutions, 0 insertions, 0 deletions
bke=>bike with 0 substitutions, 0 insertions, 1 deletions
ca =>van with 2 substitutions, 0 insertions, 0 deletions
clss=>class with 0 substitutions, 0 insertions, 1 deletions
```

You might want to investigate Python's [difflib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) module with a similar approach used here.